# MySQL: get average of value from query

Tags: mysql

I have 3 table.

```
Users --> UID, Name, Lat, Longg, Pic
Profile --> pid, uid,City, State, About
Feedback--> fid, uid, ratingby, txnid, rating, feedback_type
```

Feedback_type can be 1-4 from same txnid. So, if user is giving feedback for all the questions then there will be 4 records for same.

Now i need to show the user details along with the average feedback.

Below is the query i have written so far.

```
SELECT
                    a.name,
                    a.uid,
                    b.city,
                    a.pic,
                    b.state,
                    b.about
                FROM
                    users AS a
                INNER JOIN profile AS b
                ON
                    a.uid = b.uid
```

I am not sure how can i get the average value from feedback table.

I need show user average feedback and to be more specific. Average of all 4 feedback separately.

Also advise if my approach is good or is there any other best practice that i need to follow.

**Edit**

I can fetch the single record from feedback.

```
SELECT uid, avg(rating) FROM `feedback` WHERE uid= 8
```

But not sure how can i get the average for different feedback_type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to create a sub-table to find the average ratings of each type from the Feedbackback table (you can categorize `feedback_type` for calculating average by using `group by f.uid, f.feedback_type`). After that, you just need to join the resulting query table with the Users and Profile table to get additional data such as Name, City, etc.

```
SELECT u1.Name, ar.uid, ar.average_rating, ar.feedback_type, p.City, u1.Pic, p.State, p.About
FROM (
  SELECT f.uid, f.feedback_type, AVG(f.rating) AS average_rating
  FROM Feedback AS f
  WHERE f.uid=8
  GROUP BY f.uid, f.feedback_type
) AS ar
INNER JOIN Users AS u1 ON ar.uid=u1.UID
INNER JOIN Profile AS p ON ar.uid=p.uid;
```

Update: If alias is not working, an alternative approach would be to create a temporary table to calculate user's average rating and use the table to join with Users and Profile tables like above

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ar
SELECT uid, feedback_type, AVG(rating) AS average_rating
FROM Feedback
WHERE uid=8
GROUP BY uid, feedback_type;

SELECT Users.Name, ar.uid, ar.average_rating, ar.feedback_type, Profile.City, Users.Pic, Profile.State, Profile.About
FROM ar
INNER JOIN Users ON ar.uid=Users.UID
INNER JOIN Profile ON ar.uid=Profile.uid;
```

Update: If you need to put the records of 4 feedback types in different columns, you only need to group by `uid` in `ar` table and use `CASE` in `AVG` to filter out the feedback_type to calculate the average in each column

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ar
SELECT 
    uid,
    AVG(CASE WHEN feedback_type = 1 THEN rating END) AS average_rating_1,
    AVG(CASE WHEN feedback_type = 2 THEN rating END) AS average_rating_2,
    AVG(CASE WHEN feedback_type = 3 THEN rating END) AS average_rating_3,
    AVG(CASE WHEN feedback_type = 4 THEN rating END) AS average_rating_4
FROM Feedback
WHERE uid=8
GROUP BY uid;

SELECT
    Users.Name,
    ar.uid,
    ar.average_rating_1,
    ar.average_rating_2,
    ar.average_rating_3,
    ar.average_rating_4,
    ar.feedback_type,
    Profile.City,
    Users.Pic,
    Profile.State,
    Profile.About
FROM ar
INNER JOIN Users ON ar.uid=Users.UID
INNER JOIN Profile ON ar.uid=Profile.uid;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am testing it. Voted up.

Comment: I am still struggling to make it work. Getting Syntax error wherever ar.uid and other values. it looks like it is not recognising ar as a alias or something.

Comment: @Rocx Could you try the new code I just updated to see if it works? I think I made a mistake putting `WHERE` after `GROUP BY` so it could be causing syntax error

Comment: If it's not working, could you run only the `select` command inside the first `from` to see if there's any issue with that?

Comment: Group By one i have already rectified.But it is also not giving correct result. I have total 8 records in table for this id and i am getting 8 as output. I am expecting 4 values respect to feedback_type. Ignore this comment

Comment: ar.uid=u1.UID is giving error #1054 - Unknown column 'ar.uid' in 'on clause'

Comment: i got it working thanks a lot for your help. Now i am getting the output but unfortunatly i am getting 4 records. Need to think how it can come in single record.

Comment: Since there are 4  feedback types, it should be calculating average rating of the 4 types separately, right? Or do you also need to filter out which feedback_type to calculate?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221982/discussion-between-rocx-and-viethtran).

Answer (score 0):

You can get the avg value using this query `SELECT AVG(column_name) FROM table_name WHERE condition;`.
To get more columns you should try

```
SELECT AVG(column_name_1) AS a, AVG(column_name_2) AS b, AVG() AS c, AVG() AS d FROM table_name WHERE condition
```

I hope i was helpful.

Comment: Thanks Daniele for your answer but my table is not having different columns otherwise i have used the same which you are suggesting.